# Thresholds for NTP Offset Monitoring

Tags: unix, monitoring, ntp, health-monitoring

I am trying to write a monitoring utility on Linux, which will:
- Find out the current offset of the local system clock, when compared to the immediate Stratum 4 NTP server.
- I am fetching this 'offset' number through the { ntptime -c } utility. 
- The offset being collected is in milliseconds.

This is all working well. **But here's my question:**
- What should be treated as the warning and critical thresholds for the offset value?

After looking at the Nagios { check_ntp_time } utility's info web page, I see an 'example' usage of 0.5 seconds (500ms) as warning and 1.0 secs (1000ms) as the critical threshold.

Do we have any *standard* threshold values for NTP offsets?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible for anyone to answer this question for you. It is a lot like me asking you "what vehicle should I purchase for work?" You do not know what my professional vehicle requirements are and I do not know what your time requirements are. You need to ask yourself "What are my time requirements? How will my system operate with a time difference of X seconds? 2*X seconds? Do I have any regulatory requirements?"

*Assuming you do not have any time critical tasks (and it sounds like you do not):* A standard ntp installation  (4 separate sources of time) should not exceed the limits you quoted from Nagios during normal/healthy operation. If those limits are exceeded  for more than 15 minutes something is broken in your ntp infrastructure.

Comment: I think this should be a comment, not an answer.